# unable to detect SSD

Tags: ssd, devices

- Optiplex 3090 Micro
- SATA SSD installed in Optiplex
- Ubuntu USB installer

The USB installer boots, however the Ubuntu is unable to detect the SSD.

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

returns only the USB device: /dev/sda

What are the steps to connect the SSD to `/dev/sdb`?

```
Is there a BIOS settings requirement?
```

My BIOS is current and settings include:

System Configuration → SATA Operation   AHCI
Security → PTT Security/PTT On  Disabled
Secure Boot → Secure Boot Enable    Disabled
PSecure Boot → Secure Boot Mode Audit Mode
Intel Software Guard Extensions → Intel SGX Enable  Disabled
Power Management → Deep Sleep Control   Disabled
Power Management → USB Wake Support Disabled
Power Management → Wake on LAN/WLAN Lan only
Power Management → Block Sleep  Disabled
POST Behavior → Fastboot    Minimal
Virtualization Support → VT For Direct I/O  Disabled

Comment: You likely have a hardware problem.  /dev/sda should be the boot device.  The USB port should be something like dm-0

Comment: When properly connected, `lsblk -e7 -d -o model,name,size,rota,type` should provide relevant information about your SSD alongside all the other drives. It should also be seen by the command in your question, so I agree with @jones0610: there is probably a hardware problem with the drive or the connection to it.

Comment: My systems always promoted a flash drive to first drive or sda. Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? Install to my Dell recognized NVMe drive using an Intel VMD driver, without changing UEFI setting to AHCI. Many older Ubuntu versions & SATA based systems needed change to AHCI. But if dual booting with Windows you need to install AHCI driver into Windows for it to work.

Comment: I just realized that I was trying to install 2017 software on a 2020 computer.  I fixed this by installing 22.04 Ubuntu.  I guess I will have to run 17.x Ubuntu in a VM (proxmox)?